# Lacking unicode fonts : a Firefox on my french Debian 9.8 displays squares instead of khmer characters. Is there an easy way to install many fonts?

Tags: debian, fonts, unicode

When I open [the Ratanakiri province wiki page](https://km.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%9E%81%E1%9F%81%E1%9E%8F%E1%9F%92%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%8F%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%82%E1%9E%B7%E1%9E%9A%E1%9E%B8) (Cambodia) with `Firefox` on my french installation of `Debian 9.8`, it replaces all khmer characters by typical squares. If it happens, some others languages have chances to not being displayed well too : thaï and others.

Its a matter of fonts. But how install those missing easily ? I don't know the command to use : is it a simple `.deb` to execute ? Does a convenient tool exist ? I would like to avoid choosing in long lists of available fonts : I wouldn't really understand what could be inside, and if they are really accurate or not.

How can I make my `Debian` able to display a large part (of course, not all !) of the characters shown in the world ?

Comment: try to install firefox-esr-l10n-all

Comment: @ctac_ Looking at it's description, it seems to offer localisations to Firefox (Menus entries, and so on), and not fonts.